# How To Repeat Notifications React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) for local notifications but for some reason, I can't get the notifications to repeat each day. Even with having "repeatType: day" in the object. Does anyone know how to repeat local notifications for iOS using this library?

Here's the code I currently wrote to do this:

```
  var trigger = new Date();
  trigger.setDate(trigger.getDate()+1);
  trigger.setHours(7);
  trigger.setMinutes(0);
  trigger.setMilliseconds(0);
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    message: "Your Daily Schedule is Ready.", // (required)
    date: trigger, // in 60 secs
    allowWhileIdle: false, // (optional) set notification to work while on doze, default: false
    repeatType: "day", // (optional) Repeating interval. Check 'Repeating Notifications' section for more info.
  });
  trigger = new Date();
  trigger.setDate(trigger.getDate());
  trigger.setHours(22);
  trigger.setMinutes(30);
  trigger.setMilliseconds(0);
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({ 
    message: "Your Evening Schedule is Ready.", // (required)
    date: trigger, // in 60 secs
    allowWhileIdle: false, // (optional) set notification to work while on doze, default: false
    repeatType: "day", // (optional) Repeating interval. Check 'Repeating Notifications' section for more info.
  });
```